# Moodle - Events log

Tags: php, moodle

I am new developing and using moodle. I was wondering if there is a log where I can see all the events triggered when I do an specific action?

I know I could build a plugin which listen to all events and log them myself but wondering if moodle has already something like that.

I am using moodle:

3.3.3+ (Build: 20171123)
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your standard SQL log table or did you enable any other logging?
I'm not sure if all events are registeerd here, but at least the core events which come directly from moodle core and the native moodle plugins

[image: elog table]

Comment: logstore_standard is the default table name if you use default logging tools